# How to get scrollbar for dynamic width?

Tags: css, width

i have given width in percentage to my project. but internal things have fixed width. when browser resizes things are come outside of divs and no scrollbar is made. what can i do for this problem?

Comment: Well no one can reply to this unless you show your markup and css style code here...

Answer (score 0):

use Overflow-y or overflow-x :auto

Comment: Also `overflow: hidden;` with a fixed `width`

Answer (score 0):

Setting the containing DIVs' "overflow" property to "auto" will show a scrollbar when needed. If you want this to apply only to the horizontal/vertical direction you can use "overflow-x"/"overflow-y" respectively. 
E.g.:

CSS

```
#container {
    width: 50%;
    overflow: auto;

    /* For illustration only */
    border:2px dotted green;
}

#fixedWidth {
    width: 300px;

    /* For illustration only */
    border:2px solid red
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="fixedWidth">Fixed-width div</div>
</div>
```

Short illustration here: http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/YhAJk/